# Windows task scheduler run a task from monday to saturday every 5 minutes

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I would like to create a Windows task scheduler run a task from monday to saturday every 5 minutes. So far I have only figured out how to run either of them but not combine both criterias.

```
schtasks /create /tn "LC_GO" /tr "C:\USERS\LK5300\DESKTOP\copyDirectory.bat" /sc minute /mo 5
```

or

```
schtasks /create /tn "LC_GO" /tr "C:\USERS\LK5300\DESKTOP\copyDirectory.bat" /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI
```

could someone please advice how to combine them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there any reason for you to not use Task Scheduler UI instead of command line? There's an option to create a weekly recurring event there, then set days on which task should occur and tick option to repeat it every 5 minutes

Comment: yes there is a reason for it. because this bat file is used to run on multiple pc, it would be easier to just double click a bat file that creates everything, than to go every cpu to set up the tasks

Comment: `schtasks /create /tn "LC_GO" /tr "C:\USERS\LK5300\DESKTOP\copyDirectory.bat" /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /RI 5` try this one. /RI option is for repetitipon interval

Comment: hi Maciej, now the duration default to 1 hour, if I want to run it everyday from monday to saturday, every 5 minutes, do i put /du 24:00

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx here you will find an explanation of all options of `schtasks`. I'm not sure however how /du works in this example - I think you should try and see which way it works

Comment: When i try to add more than one day i get this error: 
`ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'TUE'
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage. `

Im trying to run @MaciejBaranowski code